# Cyclic Template

Tags: c++, templates, cyclic-reference

Suppose template class A is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    B<T> b;
};
```

Suppose template class B is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
    A<T> a;
};
```

Ideally, these classes would be defined in separate headers with inlined implementations. However, this would cause a cyclic inclusion problem. One solution is to put the implementation of the templated classes into a cpp file. However, this would require specialized template instantiations.

Is there a way to keep the implementation of the classes inlined and avoid a cyclic inclusion dependency? I would like to avoid using pointers if it is possible.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: You cannot do this, since it would require an infinite amount of memory. You have to use pointers or references here.

Comment: @classdaknok_t yes, I think you are correct. I may need to use pointers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward declare your classes and use header guards (or non-standard #pragma once).
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.11

Note that two classes cannot fully contains an object of each other. This would describe an object of infinite size...
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.12

Comment: Wouldn't forward declaring the class only work if he were holding a pointer (or reference) to the other class?

Comment: Yes one of the class at least must reference the other with a pointer or reference. It would be a non-sens anyway otherwise since it would describe a infinitely large object. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.12